# How can i use my Controller in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with my Controller class: I create my project with maven and I add the dependencies for hibernate and Spring. When I start the app I can go in the first page from the servlet, but when I call any method I get 404. I try many solutions, but no one work, I use a web logic server, there is some particular configuration for this server? In the project this is my actual situation:

AppController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "/two", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String two() {
            System.out.println("work?");
            return "newFile";
        }

}
```

i try also with ModelAndView

registration.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Title</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         form {
         display: inline-block;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/two" method="GET">
         <p class="message">//Not registered? 
            <input type="submit" value="Create an account">
         </p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
  <!DOCTYPE web-app
   PUBLIC “-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN”
   “http://java.sun.com/dtd/Web-app_2_3.dtd”>
<web-app>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>LDSServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.reply.servlet.LDSServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>LDSServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
   <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
         <value>/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
         <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.reply.utility")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        mesageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.reply</groupId>
  <artifactId>LDSSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>LDSSpring</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


  <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <oracle.connector.version>18.1.0.1</oracle.connector.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>









         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In the JSP and in the method I try to write the value for call method with / and without, but the result is the same. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem, the process "oracle xe tns listener" use my port 8080, i suppose the server block the call on controller. I found this solution because i try to start my application on tomcat and i had the port busy, so I termitate the process and my application go on tomcat and web logic server :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you having new controller component and request mapping which should be invoked on form submission.

I see the below issues in xml configuration

you are not using spring `DispatcherServlet` in **web.xml**. This class is responsible for processing and handles the request and forwards to appropriate controller

You are defining the mapping in **web.xml** with class `com.reply.servlet.LDSServlet`. how would the `LDSServlet` class look like?

Basically `DispatcherServlet`, will process the configuration (Controller classes and request mappings) and uses this for picking the appropriate controller while request arrives.

EDIT:

you should be including the `context-path` in the form action.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i try this, but no work. I think is a problem with Web logic Server, i try to launch project on tomcat and it works. Do you know about web logic?

Answer (score 0):

try this way, it is work fine with me.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }
```